# Django session handling

Tags: sqlalchemy, django-orm

I am building a django application. Using SQLAlchemy as ORM for saving data like purchase order for the user . However want to use django ORM for the session middleware.

Is it a bad design decision to use both of these ORM components ?

If I should use only one ORM , which one I should use.

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

If you're going with Django, you probably chose it because you feel it gives you more of what's needed for your project than the other Python web frameworks. If you use SQLAlchemy with Django, you're losing a lot of what Django gives you (e.g. tie-in with the forms library, the large collection of django apps, etc.)

Also, I wouldn't recommend using both. It's not something that would be impossible, but I just don't see the advantage to forcing yourself to go back and forth between two completely different APIs to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've had no issues using both.  I use Django's model for handling session data and user authentication, and SQLAlchemy for the database my application uses.

I find SQLAlchemy is easier to work with.  However:

- You can't easily manage security / user groups for your SQlAlchemy objects.  (Use Django for those components)
- I wouldn't recommend having SQLAlchemy and Django to access the same tables, it's better off with one ORM.

Otherwise - if your SQLAlchemy tables are separate from Django, and aren't required for security, form generation, or accessing Django tables directly, then it works great.  I don't use Django's forms, and so most everything except for my session & user data is in SQLAlchemy.

If you had to use only one, use the Django ORM, because otherwise you lose out on a lot of features built into Django, and you might as well go with another framework like pylons.